# Regex for extracting price from html as text

Tags: javascript, regex, web-scraping

So there's some html as string like:

```
     3.399<sup>99</sup> <span>Dineros</span> bla bla
```

or even

```
     3,399<sup>99</sup> <span>Dollars</span> bla bla
```

and I need some regex that applied to this string would give:

```
["3399", "99"]
```

so that I can eventually get a Number from the integer and decimal part

Comment: The obligatory [regex to parse html, why not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not), and quesions showing not even minimal effort are off-topic

Comment: @baao how would you flag this question?

Comment: flag for low quality @evolutionxbox, or vote to close once you have 3000

Comment: Give it a try here and see how you get on http://regexpal.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/.

Comment: @baao sorry, I meant what to choose when voting to close.

Comment: yea thanks alot i'll do it myself

Comment: Ah, I use - Questions asking as "why isn't this code working..." - but too broad would also apply @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to fetch the strings and using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method generate the number array by replacing the dot or comma.

```js
var str = '3.399<sup>99</sup> <span>Dineros</span> bla bla';

console.log(
  str
  // get the pattern matching substrings
  .match(/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/g)
  // iterate and generate the Number
  .map(function(d) {
    // parse the generated string
    return Number(
      // replace the dot or comma
      d.replace(/[.,]/, '')
    )
  })
)
```

Comment: I like this, but assumes all numbers in some HTML is desired.

Comment: there was a previous answer with a regex like `/\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?/g`, is there any notable difference?

Comment: @RobyRodriguez :  `(?:` for non-capturing - both would provide same, since there is global flag match will not store the captured value